# Burrows error: Unknown Kafka Version: 1.0.0 [recovered]

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

While trying to run Burrows I am getting this error:

```
Reading configuration from /Users/username/burrows-my-config/
panic: Unknown Kafka Version: 1.0.0 [recovered]
    panic: Unknown Kafka Version: 1.0.0 [recovered]
    panic: Unknown Kafka Version: 1.0.0

...
```

I installed it following the instructions in https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow

My config file has:

```
[client-profile.notls]
client-id="burrow-test"
kafka-version="1.0.0"
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

EDIT: It shows the same error with kafka 0.10.2.1

Comment: what version of burrows are you using?

Comment: I would assume he's using Burrows v1.0.0, as that's the latest version, and he says he's following the instructions.

Comment: Yes, the latest one. I just did go get github.com/linkedin/Burrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below link and issue.

To specify 1.0.0 as the version, you need to be running the latest master build, not the release build.

https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/issues/366